# How to set HttpHeader on individual request using HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, webclient

I have an `HttpClient` that is shared across multiple threads:

```
public static class Connection
{
    public static HttpClient Client { get; }

    static Connection()
    {
        Client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(Config.APIUri)
        };

        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Keep-Alive", "timeout=600");
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }
}
```

It has some default headers I put onto each request.  However, when I use it, I want to add on a header for *just* that request:

```
var client = Connection.Client;
StringContent httpContent = new StringContent(myQueueItem, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

httpContent.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken); // <-- Header for this and only this request
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/api/devices/data", httpContent);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

When I do this, I get the exception:

> {"Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with
>   HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and
>   content headers with HttpContent objects."}

I couldn't find another way to add request headers to this request.  If I modify the `DefaultRequestHeaders` on `Client`, I run into thread issues and would have to implement all sorts of crazy locking.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [SendAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138176(v=vs.118).aspx) to send a [HttpRequestMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage(v=vs.118).aspx).

In the message you can setup the [uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.requesturi(v=vs.118).aspx), [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.method(v=vs.118).aspx), [content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.content(v=vs.118).aspx) and [headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.headers(v=vs.118).aspx).

Example:

```
HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/api/devices/data");
msg.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
msg.Content = new StringContent(myQueueItem, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(msg);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Awesome!  That works.  I've added my working code to your answer as well. `+1`

Comment: This doesn't actually work for me--the code compiles, but when I run it, I get an exception that says "Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects."

Not sure what the point is of having an Authorization header on a request if trying to set it throws, but I will update if I figure out a workaround.