# How to set an HttpHeader on for a specific connection of HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, web, http-headers, dotnet-httpclient

The [most suggested question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255160/how-to-set-httpheader-on-individual-request-using-httpclient) doesn't have the answer.

I would like to set a specific header for the entire http connection which `HttpClient` establishes and maintains (keep-alive is set to true), that is,

**each request** I make should contain my custom header. Obviously,

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("MyHeader", "MyValue");
```

is not an option, since it sets the header for the entire `HttpClient`, whereas I would like to have it only for the **specific connection**, which is created when I make my first call to a URL at a server.

That server then keeps the connection alive and **expects** me to have a **MyHeader** header for each subsequent request that I make while the connection is .

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this example.
On each request you can clear all request headers from your **HttpClient**.
After that add the request headers which will help you.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
```

Simply you will not instantiate your HttpClient, also set configuration for request.

Answer (score 0):

after your first call just remove it

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("keep-alive");
```

Comment: The server specifies that I should keep the connection alive after a login, or i will be forced to relog.